# End to end cryptographic methods/solutions

Tags: encryption

I want to implement secure communication for my application. The A sends a message/data and B receives it. The message should be encrypted so the internet provider would not be able to read it even if it gets intercepted.

Conditions:

- I cannot use https (but should be included for completness)
- It's possible to use other protocols then http, but not desirable

I found many sources to this problem, but decided to ask to see all alternatives and maybe create a list of methods/solutions/scenarios to this problem, since many people new to this domain spend a lot of time researching these methods. Thank you!

Comment: Why doesn't SSL work for you? How do you find the public key of your communication partner? Is there a connection where both are online at the same time, or is it store-and-forward like email?

Comment: when you say "it's possible to use other protocols then http..." did you mean https? Why is it not desirable to use well established, deeply studied security protocols?

Comment: @CodesInChaos 1.Yes there are time when they are both online.
2.The key can be stored on the recipient (implied by your "store and forward"), but was hoping for another solution than this one, considering the limitations of this method.
@ mikeazo SSL and HTTPS are already known solutions that I've taken into account, i'm interested in the alternatives. Especially new protocols that are specially designed for secure communication (again, except https)

Comment: @mikeazo "did you mean https", no I meant http (since I know about the https solution already). Although I don't know how secure communication over HTTP would work except encrypting and encrypting at both ends with same or symmetric key. (Again, I'm not that good at this part, that's why I ask you guys for help). Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know for sure that both parties are online all the time then you could think about message encryption. Should we include message encryption formats like CMS, PGP and XML encryption? I think that together with SSH they are the most common formats. There are endless possibilities here though.

Comment: To be honest it's the first time I've even heard of CMS and PGP, as said before, I'm quite new to cryptography. I'm in the research phase for a secure communication method, other then the common used ones (HTTP over SSL/TLS or HTTPS).I read a bit about the formats you suggested and I think they are a possibility, are there any encryption methods that don't use certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend OpenPGP GNU has a good implementation of that that is [GPG or GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) that comes with it. Check with `gpg --version` GNU also has a windows implementation called Gpg4win.

A better place to get these answers that allows for more discussion is IRC. I suggest ##crypto on freenode.

I personally use it with Enigmail(Thunderbird add on) for my email. For more on encryption and digital signatures see [this.](http://www.secure-my-email.com/)